# How to navigate cursor between QLabels in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to navigate/move the cursor between QLabels?. If I press,  right arrow key the first left-most label will select, press the right arrow key once more, now the cursor will move from the first Qlabel to the Second one "File" and so on.  If the cursor is on the last position ("Others" label), the right arrow key is disabled.  (simply, Just like the menu bar).

```
import sys, os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Navigate_Between(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Navigate Between Labels")

        self.dashboard = QLabel("DashBoard")
        self.file = QLabel("File")
        self.master = QLabel("Master")
        self.transcation = QLabel("Transcation")
        self.reports = QLabel("Reports")
        self.others = QLabel("Others")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.dashboard)
        layout.addWidget(self.file)
        layout.addWidget(self.master)
        layout.addWidget(self.transcation)
        layout.addWidget(self.reports)
        layout.addWidget(self.others)
        self.setLayout(layout)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Navigate_Between()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: And what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Use it in my code. As of my feelings, menu bar is not good. So create a colourful menubar @musicamante

Comment: If you want to have a widget that behaves like a menu bar, then tell that, as your question right now is meaningless, since a QLabel is only intended for *display* purposes, not for interaction. What you're probably looking for is to set a proper [focus policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop), but you need to clarify exactly how you expect it to work and behave, as it's really unclear.

Comment: what do you want after last label ? move to first label? You may bind key event to assign own function which will move to first label.

Comment: Yes, I want a menubar style

Comment: Yes  move between labels @furas

Comment: on my Linux `Labels` don't react on any key - they can't be select even with mouse. And when I use `QPushButton` then all works as expected - it move from last to first when I press arrow.